# Working with FTL and Servlets

Tags: freemarker

Can I pass an Object variable from FTL file using the Request using methods like setAttribute/setParameter to the Servlet?
There is no clear documentation of how to use FTL with Servlet's when I want to post a request from FTL to a servlet.

My FTL file needs to be submitted to a Servlet, to which I need to pass data.

I am getting data into the FTL file from the previous Servlet, but I am stuck at how to send it to the next servlet.

Each of these servlet's are responsible to certain functionality.

Comment: FreeMarker API talks about Servlet (MVC) to .ftl file interaction, it does not talk much about vice versa. I was referring this URL : http://fmpp.sourceforge.net/freemarker/pgui_misc_servlet.html , this talks about the Session/Request/Application scopes but then, only to be set from the Servlet side to be used inside the FTL. It does not talk about what if I need to go further!

Comment: For now I am setting the data in the session in my first servlet which calls the the FTL and then getting the data from the session in the 2nd servlet that is called from the FTL file. It does not look like I can edit the Request/Session/Application objects inside the FTL files.

Answer (score 1):

Templates meant to be used as MVC View only, so in theory you should not do things like that in them. I mean manipulating Servlet-specific stuff directly, or anything that's not a presentation concern. If your architecture needs something like invoking other servlets on a way that `<@include_page .../>` can't do, wrap that into a custom directive or custom method (`TemplateDirectoveModel` and `TemplateMethodModel` interfaces) which conveys the high-level meaning when you look at the template, and hides the gory technical details inside the Java implementation, where you can do whatever you want, as it's Java. Looking at the implementation of `include_page` is possibly a good starting point. You can drop the new directive or method into the data-model, or into the `Configuration` as shared variable, or pull it inside an `#import`-ed/`#include`-ed common template with `<#assign myDirective = 'com.example.MyDirective'?new()>`.